# If I have a question in the field of spectrum analysis, where should I ask?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about spectrum analysis. Maybe I should ask the question in the Mathematics, But it still a signal Processing Quiz, So, where should I ask?

Answer (score 2):

The folks over at [DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) would have the specialized knowledge you're looking for.

Comment: thanks a lot! helpful